# Linq group by multiple as well as blank values

Tags: c#, linq

I need to be able to group by multiple values but also match when a value is blank.

```
    public class ExampleClass
    {
        public string FieldX { set; get; }
        public string FieldY { set; get; }
        public string FieldZ { set; get; }
        public string FieldA { set; get; }
        public string FieldB { set; get; }
        public string FieldC { set; get; }
    }

    var obj1 = new ExampleClass{
            FieldA = "AAA",
            FieldB = "BBB",
            FieldC = "CCC",
            FieldX = "Matched",
            FieldY = "Matched",
            FieldZ = "Matched"
        };

    var obj2 = new ExampleClass{
        FieldA = "ada a",
        FieldB = "BBBada ",
        FieldC = "CCadasd aC",
        FieldX = "Matched",
        FieldY = "Matched",
        FieldZ = "Matched"
    };
    var obj3 = new ExampleClass{
        FieldA = "AfsfAA",
        FieldB = "BBsfsfB",
        FieldC = "CsfsghsCC",
        FieldX = "",
        FieldY = "Matched",
        FieldZ = "Matched"
    };

    var obj4 = new ExampleClass{
        FieldA = "AAA",
        FieldB = "BBB",
        FieldC = "CCC",
        FieldX = "Not Matched",
        FieldY = "Not Matched",
        FieldZ = "Matched"
    };
    var list = new List<ExampleClass>(new ExampleClass[] { obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4 } );
    var grp = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.FieldX, x.FieldY, x.FieldZ });
```

So now grp equals

```
//grp = [{[obj1, obj2]}, {[obj3]}, {[obj4]}]
```

But I need grp to equal

```
//grp = [{[obj1, obj2, obj3]}, {[obj4]}]
```

Hopefully there's an efficient way to achieve this without multiple nested looping.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why `{[obj1, obj2, obj3]}, {[obj4]}`, but not `{[obj1, obj2]}, {[obj3, obj4]}`? Note, that `obj3` **matches** `obj4` : `FieldY` and `FieldZ` are equal and since `obj3.FieldX` is empty it **matches** `obj4.FieldX`

Comment: Instead of grouping by `x.FieldX` and so on, you need to group by `x.FieldX == "" || x.FieldX == "Matched"`. But maybe done a bit tidier. In essence you're coercing into both empty and matched into a single boolean value for X, Y and Z

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you are correct, I've edited obj4 so that it shouldn't match with any of the others.

Comment: @AFriend unfortunately the values are not static and are not known so I cannot hardcode the boolean value.

Comment: The point DmitryBychenko is making, which you seem to have missed, is there is a logical issue here.  If a blank value can equal either "Match" _or_ "Unmatched" then there is no fixed grouping, (ie items can go in several places) because your concept of equality is NOT transitive (ie X= blank and Y=blank but X!=Y).  Thus you would need to have something other than naive grouping.

Of course if you just want blank to match up with one of the values, "Matched" say, this is not a problem.  Otherwise you need to think _hard_ about DmitryBychenko's original point.

Comment: @tolanj thanks for your comments. I understand there's a duplicate grouping issue here and I apologise for not making it clearer in the question. In those instances where an entity can be matched in multiple groups it can either be duplicated across different groupings or be distinctly grouped in any, i.e. if it's grouped with one then it cannot be matched to another group. Thank you again.

Comment: Okay if I understand you correctly you could iterate through you list until you hit the 1st positive value for each field, storing them.  Then initialise a comparer that defaults the fields to that value for comparison.  Since you have decided your defaults (ie what blank is going to be equivalent to) that comparer can have strong and sensible GetHash and equality set up.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might help you
(I'm adding a [dotnet fiddle url](https://dotnetfiddle.net/daU79P) so you could play with it)

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public class ExampleClass
    {
        public string FieldX { set; get; }
        public string FieldY { set; get; }
        public string FieldZ { set; get; }
        public string FieldA { set; get; }
        public string FieldB { set; get; }
        public string FieldC { set; get; }
    }

    public class IncludeBlankComparer : IEqualityComparer<(string a, string b, string c)>
    {
        public static bool IsBlank(string s) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);

        private static bool IsMatchOrBlankMatch(string left, string right) => left == right || IsBlank(left) || IsBlank(right);

        public bool Equals((string a, string b, string c) first, (string a, string b, string c) second)
        { 
            if (first == second) return true;
            return IsMatchOrBlankMatch(first.a, second.a)
                && IsMatchOrBlankMatch(first.b, second.b)
                && IsMatchOrBlankMatch(first.c, second.c);
        }

        public int GetHashCode((string a, string b, string c) s) => 0;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj1 = new ExampleClass{
                FieldA = "AAA",
                FieldB = "BBB",
                FieldC = "CCC",
                FieldX = "Matched",
                FieldY = "Matched",
                FieldZ = "Matched"
            };

        var obj2 = new ExampleClass{
            FieldA = "ada a",
            FieldB = "BBBada ",
            FieldC = "CCadasd aC",
            FieldX = "Matched",
            FieldY = "Matched",
            FieldZ = "Matched"
        };
        var obj3 = new ExampleClass{
            FieldA = "AfsfAA",
            FieldB = "BBsfsfB",
            FieldC = "CsfsghsCC",
            FieldX = "",
            FieldY = "Matched",
            FieldZ = "Matched"
        };

        var obj4 = new ExampleClass{
            FieldA = "AAA",
            FieldB = "BBB",
            FieldC = "CCC",
            FieldX = "Not Matched",
            FieldY = "Not Matched",
            FieldZ = "Matched"
        };

        var list = new List<ExampleClass>(new ExampleClass[] { obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4 } );
        var grp = list.GroupBy(x => ( x.FieldX, x.FieldY, x.FieldZ ), new IncludeBlankComparer());

        grp.Dump();
    }
}
```

**Explanation**: You can pass a custom comparer to the the GroupBy method.
Of course the comparer must handle the comparison of the same types as the key.
Note that I've changed the key selector from anonymous class (in which I cant reference internal members) to a tuple (in which I can).

**Note**: This solution will only work with a tuple key that has 3 string parts.

**Note 2**: Due to the hacky nature of this solution I had to use `GetHashCode() => 0`. This will work as the [implementation of the lookup](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/3.1/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Lookup.cs#L201) compares both for equality and for hashcode equality, and won't break the implementation of GroupBy, however it is not a "clean" solution per-se.

Comment: The solution been hacky means that the performance is bad. The computational complexity has gone from O(n) to O(n²). I don't know if this is something that can be fixed, given the strange requirements of the problem.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Its still O(n) where n is the number of total groups. 
its just that we don't enjoy the best case solution which is in O(1) because no longer have a chance to hit the group with a simple hashcode computation you always have to compare at most all the groups to find your group

Comment: O(n) is the search for one element. For all elements is O(n²). So the whole operation is O(n²). With proper hashing would be O(1) for one element, and O(n) for the whole operation. In other words the computation has gone from linear to quadratic.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias its been 8 years since I last gave a deep though about O-notation. 
Mind to walking me through? Standard comparison for each element `e_i` I'd be comparing its hashcode and the keys for equality
So in the best case you've found the group in `Ω(1)` and in worst case in `O(g)` where g is the number of groups
In the hacky solution you still for each element `e_i` have to compare all hashcodes (which are always equal) and compare the keys. The difference is that in the hacky solution the lower boundary for finding the group is bound by `θ(n)`

Comment: My theoretical knowledge of the [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is pretty limited. I only know the basics. But it's pretty obvious to me that by giving the same hash to all groups, all the advantages of hashing have gone and we are back to the slow serial searching.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yeah, well you no longer have the best case scenario of finding a group in O(1) you have the worst case scenario of O(n) which is always the case with dictionaries. However, the more I think of if the more it looks like O(n*g) where n is the number of items and g is the number of groups, which can in worst case scenario n = g we which case `O(n*g) < O(n*n) = O(n^2)` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯